# DIAL Protocol Android sample application

Tags: android

I am interested in implementing DIAL Protocol in my application.
On the DIAL official site (http://www.dial-multiscreen.org) they have provided sample of server and client in C/C++.
But I want to use it in Android code, so anyone having any DIAL sample code used in Android Application.

OR is it that we have to reuse this sample code of C/C++ to write our Android application?